# while-loop doesn't end in c++

Tags: c++, while-loop

So, this is a small piece of code out of my bigger c++ program. All of the relevant parts are included.

```
char weekDay;
char inputWeekDay;
char daysInTheWeek[7] = { 'm','t','w','p','f','s','z' } ;
int days = 1723;

weekDay = daysInTheWeek[days%7] ;
cout << weekDay << endl ;

cin >> inputWeekDay ;

while (inputWeekDay != ('m'&'t'&'w'&'p'&'f'&'s'&'z')) {
    cout << "Your input isn't one of the above.\nTry again." << endl ;
    cin >> inputWeekDay ;
}
if (inputWeekDay == weekDay) {
    cout << "Your input is correct." ;
} 
else {
    cout << "Your input isn't correct.\nYou will now get kicked out of this program." ;
    return 1;
}
```

When I run this part, and I type for example 'g' when I get asked for inputWeekDay, it gives me 'Your input isn't right.\nYou will now get kicked out of this program.' error and asks me again, which is what should be happening. But after that when I type for example 'm', which isn't equal to weekDay but isn't one of the conditions in the while-loop, it keeps me in the while-loop and I get the error again. The same goes for when I type in the right 'weekDay', it still gives me the error message.

Any ideas what could cause this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're completely misusing logical and bitwise operators.

Comment: What you are doing is an AND of the 7 chars and compare it with inputWeekDay, and that is hardly ever equal to inputWeekDay

Comment: You performed the bitwise `&` operator in while loop checking...

Comment: Yes, I see what you are doing: it is humanly logical, and it would be nice if that worked, but it just doesn't work in C++.  Your program wants an entirely different structure, unfortunately.

Comment: Lol downvoting just because a error we all did in the past?

Comment: Take a look at my answer, it can be really useful to write it in a bit different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is comparing whether `inputWeekDay` is equal to the bitwise-AND of many characters.

Presumably you want to compare whether it's equal to *any* of the characters.

You could do that with a condition like this:

```
while ( inputWeekDay != 'm'
    && inputWeekDay != 't'
    && inputWeekDay != 'w'
    ...
```

But that gets old fast. Another way would be to use a `switch` statement in a `do-while` loop.

```
bool isValid = false;
do {
    switch ( inputWeekDay ) {
       case 'm':
       case 't':
         ...
         isValid = true;
         break;

       default:
         isValid = false;
         break;
   }
   if ( ! isValid ) {
       cout << "Your input isn't one of the above.\nTry again." << endl ;
       cin >> inputWeekDay ;
   } 
} while ( ! isValid );
```

Comment: Well, check your top 4 lines. The first two are duplicates of the second two, with AND changed to OR. That's what I see anyway. :(

Comment: @Almo - Ah. I stumbled over your fix for my original mistake. Thanks for catching both!

Comment: For now I'll use the first solution, and I'll have a look into switches aswell. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Your while has to be something like:

```
while(inputWeekDay != 'm' && inputWeekDay != 't' && ...)
```

So that you are really checking that `inputWeekDay` is really different to all the given values.

EDIT: you can make it much easier as follows:

```
std::string weekDay("mtwpfsz");
...
while (str.find(inputWeekDay)!=std::string::npos)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for more elegant solution than long condition or a long list of case labels!

Comment: Thanks, will certainly look into this :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a bitwise AND operation on all of your chars, when what you want is a logical AND, also you must list each condition separately. C++ does not support such a style as you have in your while statement.

```
while (inputWeekDay != ('m'&'t'&'w'&'p'&'f'&'s'&'z')) {
```

should become

```
while ( inputWeekDay != 'm'
        && inputWeekDay != 't'
        && inputWeekDay != 'w'
        && inputWeekDay != 'p'
        && inputWeekDay != 'f'
        && inputWeekDay != 's'
        && inputWeekDay != 'z'){
```

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is with bitwise-AND operator(&). You should use logical and(&&).

Answer (score 1):

Since they're `char`s, you could spare yourself the loop and declare:

```
const char *daysInTheWeek = "mtwpfsz";
```

then:

```
while (strchr(daysInTheWeek, inputWeekDay) == NULL) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you wrote the condition incorrectly. Operator & is the bitwise AND operator.

To check that the entered value is among the values of the array it is better to use standard algorithm `std::find`

For example

```
while ( std::find( daysInTheWeek, daysInTheWeek + 7, inputWeekDay ) == daysInTheWeek + 7 )
{
   //...
}
```

This loop can be written also like

```
while ( std::find( std::begin( daysInTheWeek ), std:;end( daysInTheWeek ), inputWeekDay ) == std::end( daysInTheWeek ) )
{
   //...
}
```

Or you could define array daysInTheWeek as

```
char daysInTheWeek[] = { "mtwpfsz" };
```

and use standard C function `strchr`
For example

```
while ( std::strchr( daysInTheWeek, inputWeekDay ) == NULL )
{
   //...
}
```